# Using rack-timeout gem on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I'm trying to use the [rack-timeout gem](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) on Rails. I added the line `gem 'rack-timeout'` to my Gemfile and ran `bundle install`. (It shows `Using rack-timeout (0.0.4)`) Then I submitted a request to my server. It clearly hung for more than 15 seconds without returning anything to me. What am I missing?

Comment: by default, it looks like rack-timeout defaults to 15sec.  as far as the returning - that'd be a fault of your own.. you might have bad logic somewhere

Comment: if the logic in my controller doesn't finish within 15sec, shouldn't rack-timeout just force it to return? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: well - i'm ignorant when it comes to rack-timeout.  looks like it's purpose is to "Abort requests that are taking too long." If that's true, then you might not be handling the errors correctly? looks like it returns a `Rack::Timeout::Error` if it fails.  if it does - you should have a fail safe to redirect the user

Comment: I'm also ignorant. Hopefully someone knows how to redirect the user when the request exceeds 15 seconds.

Comment: take a look at @JessWolgamott 's answer.. looks like that might be the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell Rails what to do when a Rack::Timeout error is thrown.

- If you ignore it, execution will stop after 15 seconds (or whatever you configure it to be)
- If you want to show the user a nice error, you'll need to rescue from that exception (like below).

You could do something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from Timeout::Error, with: :handle_timeout

  protected
  def handle_timeout
    render "shared/timeout"
  end
end
```